# Docker - if changes on storage are written?

Tags: docker

I have a following question:
If changes on storage are persist between restartings of container ?
For example, we add some rows to `mysql` database and restart container.  If added rows are present in database after restart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are. For each container you run, a docker volume (`docker volume -ls` to list them) is created.
However if you remove the container or create a new one for some reason, all the changes will be lost.

For a database, it is recommended to use [shared volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) between host and the container, to be able to backup the data.

You can see which volume is used by your container using `docker inspect`.

Comment: can you tell me more ? At this moment I think about it as virtual machine - own filesystem, own interfaces, own everything. Where is the key difference?

Comment: Well, it could work, but it is not the purpose of Docker. If you want to do something like a virtual machine you should go with a virtual machine. Docker runs on your host kernel, and it should be able to be started/stopped without impact, and it should be able to work even in a fresh state (wipe data). It is a different philosophy that you will get with time and usage

Answer (score 0):

Hi
To persist the data between restartings of container, you need to mount a directory from host to the container so that it's visible to the container.

please check this [how to share a directory for mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) which will help to you